# Are Bluemix Cloud Integration & Secure Gateway in High Availability?

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway, cloud-integration

I have some questions related to the functioning of Bluemix Cloud Integration & Secure Gateway.

1. Are they in High Availability?
2. Do they use virtual IP or not?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud Integration environment for Secure Gateway is full HA with a front end load balancer.  All Secure Gateways are given a bluemix hostname to contact which is backed by a public physical IP.